# Selecting the nth result of a query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010, but i think any sql or vb codes could help.

I already have a query:
*something simple like this*

```
Select namelist from names
```

let's say that it returned 5 results : (John, Jacob, James, Joe, Jerk)

Then I click button1, Label1 should change text based on the result of the query

I used this code to do so

```
Label1.text = .fields("namelist").value
```

and YES, it does change the text of Label1 into "John"

but what I want to happen is for that Label to change text into any of those query results and(like Joe or James depending on how I specify it) and not just the first result automatically.

I don't know which part of the code to edit to specify what row is to be used as the value for the label's text.
Can anyone please help me with this? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Skip` Linq operator:

```
        double[] vals = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

        double val = vals.Skip(6).First();
```

This is just an example, adapt to your specific needs.

Cheers

EDIT:

After your comment, I decided to clarify.

```
Select namelist from names
```

is your basic query, so it means that `namelist` now contains the list of names.

If you want to grab only the 5th name, then something like this:

```
var fithName = namelist.Skip(4).First();
```

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I'm sorry but I barely understand how or where I should do that part of coding :(

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for the late gratification but yeah it helped. Thank you so much man.

Comment: Well, then don't forget to flag my answer. Cheers.